# What does the "a" in the html <a> tag stand for?

Tags: html, hyperlink, tags

As  most of you know, the `<a>` tag is (mostly) used in html to make a hyperlink like

```
<a href="page.html">Click me</a>
```

But I've always wondered what the "a" in the `<a>` tag actually stands for.

Comment: You would have gotten your answer far quicker if you had just typed your question into Google.

Comment: @MrLister I got to this page from google. This question and answers were useful to me.

Comment: Yup, IMO, this page adds value to the Internet because when searching for "html what does a stand for", this page comes to the top, answering simply and specifically, while others do not--at least not on the first page.

Comment: This was called an anchor because it doubles as a fixed location on a page. When used with the hash symbol, the anchor tag allows one to link to that fixed location. The browser will scroll down and everything.

Answer (score 36):

`a` stands for *anchor*. As easy as that!

Comment: Note that `a` tags are (or used to be) used to to define the anchor (where the link lands, via the `name` attribute) as well as the outgoing link (via the `href` attribute).

Comment: @Thilo BTW OP isn't asking about how to use `<a>` but what is `a` *as is*

Comment: Right, and I think the word `anchor` makes a lot more sense with the other use (to anchor an incoming link), so I thought I would point that out, especially since many people don't know that use (and it is sort of deprecated now that you can use `id` tags on anything).

Answer (score 9):

According to [HTML Documentation part 4.5.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) the `<a>` tag refers to a HTML**Anchor**Element

Answer (score 3):

Stands for anchor tag.
The  tag defines a hyperlink, which is used to link from one page to another.

The most important attribute of the  element is the href attribute, which indicates the link's destination.